# Can I use basic iPhone 5/5s/5c with Aio Wireless "Aio Basic" plan?

Tags: iphone, unlock, cellular-data, cellular-carriers

I would like to buy an unlocked iPhone 5 or iPhone 5s, and use it with the [*Aio Basic*](http://www.aiowireless.com/shop/plans.html) plan from *Aio Wireless*, an AT&T prepaid subsidiary launched in mid-2013.

On their web-site, *Aio Basic* @ 40 USD/mo is described as including 250MB of unlimited data at 4G and 4G LTE speed (with throttling after you reach the limit), but is annotated to be "Basic phones only"; whereas *Aio Smart* @ 55 USD/mo is described as having 2GB of unlimited data, but it said to be "Basic or Smartphones".

Provided I don't mind being throttled after 250MB/mo for getting the savings, will Aio Basic work for my basic iPhone 5 or 5s?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it would appear that this is allowed, but only as long as you go the Bring-Your-Own-Device route.

In the **Bring Your Own Device** option of ordering the 40$/mo **Aio Basic** plan, you can search for **Apple iPhone 5** and, subsequently, select the **Nano SIM Card** option (the only option available), where they will also ask you for your IMEI number.

This also has been confirmed by a service representative through the online chat function:  you cannot purchase an iPhone 5 together with the 40$/mo plan, but as long as you bring your own device, going with the 40$/mo plan is completely OK.  They also claim that the throttling past the allotment would be down to 256kbps, although this is not written anywhere on the web-site itself so far.

At 40$/mo, this plan would be more expensive and with less data that [T-Mobile USA](http://prepaid-phones.t-mobile.com/prepaid-plans)'s online prepaid special 30$/mo 100 minutes + unlimited data with 5GB @ 4G plan (available only online and through Walmart), but it's still a great deal for what it is.

Comment: As of Feb 2014, it looks like the throttling may be down to 150kbps downstream, and none upstream. Source: http://www.howardforums.com/showthread.php/1802067-What-are-the-speeds-of-AIO-Wireless-after-being-throttled

Answer (score 1):

You can use an AT&T iPhone 5s on Aio wireless as well. No unlocking required. I got the iPhone 5s on launch day from Apple and went right to my local Aio wireless store here in Tampa, Florida...signed up for service, popped in their SIM card and wah-la! I ported my number over from Sprint who has the most horrible reception in Florida. I took a trip today from Tampa to Miami and have had superior LTE reception with Aio wireless. Streaming music with no issue what so ever the entire way! Thanks Aio wireless!

Comment: did you get this all with the 40$/mo plan, or the 55$/mo plan?  did you get iPhone 5s unlocked for full price (650$+), or was it locked (on a contract) with AT&T?

Comment: What is your speed? I've read AIO limits LTE to 8 megabit (not to be confused with 8 megabyte).

Comment: I got the $70 a month plan with unlimited talk/text and 7GB of data. I bought an ATT iphone 5s from apple for $650, there was no unlocking required, I went to Aio and signed up for service and popped in the SIM card and it worked!